# Remove for loop in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to remove `for loop` in pytorch.

I wrote the code as below, but it's not cool. And it doesn't use the GPU well either.

```py
for i in range(idx.shape[0]):
  for j in range(idx.shape[2]):
    for k in range(idx.shape[3]):
      for x in range(idx.shape[4]):
        for y in range(idx.shape[5]):
          default_mask[i,idx[i,0,j,k,x,y],j,k,x,y] = 0
```

And my question is:

1. Please remove the for loop from this code.
2. Give me a general way to get rid of the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`torch.scatter_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.scatter_.html) to scatter zeros by indexing `default_mask` with `idx` along `dim=1`. In other words, this correspond to the following in *pseudo-code*:

```
for i,j,k,x,y in dims:
    default_mask[i,idx[i,0,j,k,x,y],j,k,x,y] = 0
```

Since `idx` already has the same number of dimensions as `default_mask`, you just ned to expand `dim=1` to the correct number before applying the scatter function.

```
>>> x.scatter_(dim=1, index=idx.expand_as(x), value=0)
```

*The above operation is in-place*